# Add ecommerce data to mailchimp subscriber via API v3

Tags: e-commerce, mailchimp

I´m looking for a solution to add ecommerce data (like orders and order items) to my mailchimp subscriber / lists so that I´m able to segment the lists by purchase history.

There was an interface in API v2 which seams to be missing in v3:
https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/ecomm/order-add.php

Has anybody already implemented ecommerce data with API v3? Can´t find any useful information on the net.

Thanks in advance for any hint,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

Ecommerce end points aren't in v3.0 yet. You'll want to use the 2.0 end points for now.

Comment: Umg... :( Thanks. Do you know if there is anywhere a roadmap which shows ans expected date for this in V3? I don´t like the idea to add another, additional interface and mix both version.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like MailChimp does have e-commerce endpoints now http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/ecommerce/stores/

I believe the specific functionality you're asking about is found at http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/ecommerce/stores/orders/#create-post_ecommerce_stores_store_id_orders